# Вычислить размер таблицы

Tags: php, html, css

У меня есть таблица, которая выводится на сайт из базы данных с помощью php скрипта, соответственно у нее может быть различное число строк и столбцов в которых выводится фиксированного размера содержимое(например изображения). Есть ли какая нибудь функция на php или способ, что бы узнать размер(высоту и ширину) получившейся таблицы в пикселях ?

Comment: PHP на такое не способен... Только JS

Comment: @Air а на нем как можно такое сделать ?

Comment: Я если посчитать кол-во строк во время вывода на php, а потом умножить на высоту строки(если они фиксированной высоты, как говорится выше)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let div = document.getElementById('wrapper');
let img = div.querySelector('img');

console.log(getComputedStyle(div).width);
console.log(getComputedStyle(div).height);
/*или*/
function isHidden(elem) {
  return !elem.offsetWidth && !elem.offsetHeight;
}
console.log(isHidden(div));
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x200/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Image" width="100px">
</div>
```